# Service call not updating Active Record value for incrementing join model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a service that fires when a stripe checkout is completed. I am expecting a ticket to be added to the user's inventory with a unique number.

*Note the object.client_reference_id and the metadata come from the Stripe webhook and are both confirmed to be returning the correct data.*

Ticket is created and given a ticket_number based on the max_tickets value of the contest for that ticket minus the ticket that was just created.

```ruby
# services/ticket_service.rb

class TicketService
    def self.call(event)
      new(event).call
    end
  
    attr_reader :event
    def initialize(event)
      @event = event
    end
  
    def call
      user = User.find_by(id: object.client_reference_id)
      return unless user
      contest = Contest.find_by(id: object.metadata.order_item.to_i)
      # Problem code below
      user.tickets.create!(purchased: true, user_id: user.id, 
      contest_id: contest.id, ticket_number: contest.max_tickets -= 1 )

      OrderMailer.with(contest: contest).new_order_email.deliver_later

    end
  
    private
  
    def object
      @object ||= event.data.object
    end

  end
```

However every time a ticket is purchased in this manner the **contest.max_tickets -= 1** part does not seem to work as expected. I have the same ticket in my inventory with **ticket_number: 49 / 50** no matter how many times I try and purchase this ticket.

Strangely enough, when I create a ticket the same way in rails console the ticket_number gets decremented as expected 49,47,48 etc.

```
irb(main):024:0> user.tickets.create!(purchased: true, user_id: user.id, contest_id: contest.id, ticket_number: contest.max_tickets -= 1 )
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  Contest Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "contests".* FROM "contests" WHERE "contests"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "contests"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 17], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Ticket Create (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "tickets" ("contest_id", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "purchased", "ticket_number") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["contest_id", 17], ["user_id", 63], ["created_at", "2020-07-25 02:18:33.819410"], ["updated_at", "2020-07-25 02:18:33.819410"], ["purchased", true], ["ticket_number", 43]]
   (1.7ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Ticket id: 599, contest_id: 17, user_id: 63, ticket_price: nil, created_at: "2020-07-25 02:18:33", updated_at: "2020-07-25 02:18:33", purchased: true, ticket_number: 43>
```

Comment: What is `max_tickets`?

Comment: Each contest has a set number of max_tickets for sale in a raffle. This number is fixed when a contest is created.

Comment: `contest.max_tickets -= 1` this code doesnt update the row

Comment: correct ```contest.max_tickets + 1``` is the correct way to in this case increment the ticket number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `-=` does not generate the `update` query to persist whatever changes you make to the column, and it's not clear why this appears to work in your database example, because there is no `update` query against `contests` in the output to indicate it could be working.

You need to *save* the contest, after you modify its field, with `contest.save!`, and you want to do this inside a transaction to make sure both tables (`contests` and `tickets`) are updated, and with a lock to prevent multiple concurrent ticket purchases from creating a race condition:

The code you want looks something like this:

```
contest = Contest.find_by(id: object.metadata.order_item.to_i)
contest.with_lock do
  # TODO: verify max_tickets is still > 0
  user.tickets.create!(purchased: true, user_id: user.id, 
  contest_id: contest.id, ticket_number: contest.max_tickets -= 1)
  contest.save!
end
```

See Rails' [Pessimistic Locking `with_lock`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html#method-i-with_lock).

Just a few notes looking at your code:

- You should have a unique index on `tickets`, against the columns `[contest_id, ticket_number]`. It should never be possible for ticket #33 for the same contest to be given away twice.
- You should, *inside the lock* verify that `contest.max_tickets` is still greater than 0. You don't have any obvious check for this right now, unless you're relying on a validation inside the `Ticket` model. This validation is not sufficient without the above locking/index.